# How to compare custom label value in IF condition on VF page?

Tags: visualforce, customlabel

I have a requirement to compare a variable with a custom label to show or hide section on VF page. Eg:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!myVariable1}" 
                 rendered="{!IF(myVariable2 == $Label.labelValue , true, false)}" />
```

This gives me error. I think i am using incorrect syntax or something.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but why do you want this? Do you want to show the input only when the user is using a certain language? Or is the value of myVariable2 also language dependent? As for an actual attempt at an answer, I think you will have to create a function in the controller that returns the value of the label and use that on the page.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your response.. it was a miss from my end where i wasnt setting the value for myVariable2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need that formula IF? You can just do `<apex:inputText value="{!myVariable1}" rendered="{!myVariable2 == $Label.labelValue}"/>`

I just tested this in my developer org, and it works.

Just remember that you probably have to set up `myVariable2` for this to work. If you don't, then its value will default to null, and your input will never be displayed in the page.

Comment: yep.. myVariable2 wasnt set.. thanks :)